# How to trace while developing a MediaWiki extension?

Tags: mediawiki, trace, mediawiki-extensions

How to add tracing (for bug hunting) code to my MediaWiki extension?

When I add `echo "XXX";` or `var_dump(...);`, I don't see it in output (despite the code line where I put this tracing works for sure, as I checked by adding `exit(0);` instead of this tracing and watching it crashing by exit as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean debug logging ("trace" is usually used for recording what method calls happen, as in [XDebug function traces](https://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace)). [The MediaWiki debugging help page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#Logging) has some information on it, although it's not in great shape. Basically you set `$wgDebugLogGroups['mydebuglog']` to point to a logfile, and then use `wfDebugLog( 'mydebuglog', 'XXX' )`. (PSR-3-style [structured logging](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Structured_logging) is possible but requires some setting up.)

Usually `var_dump` works too, but there is a lot of stuff that happens outside of requests with a web response (jobs or heavy processing that's delayed until the response has been sent).

If you did mean tracing, [the profiling help page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Profiling) has some information.